# Can't save state in windows 8 [ Error The type or namespace name 'Common'

Tags: microsoft-metro, state-management, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Can't save state in windows 8

```
{ 
Error   The type or namespace name 'Common' ...does not exist in the namespace 'ProjectName' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 
}
```

Everything below is the default code in my App.Xaml.cs file the only line I added was

```
                ProjectNameSpace.Common.SuspensionManager.RegisterFrame(rootFrame, "appframe");
```

which is from the windows 8 tutorial here and I have followed part 1 before attempting this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986968.aspx. I have it working in another project that has the same references and using statements. There is only one namespace in the project and I even Rebuilt/Cleaned. Does anybody have any extra information?

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                rootFrame = new Frame();
                ProjectNameSpace.Common.SuspensionManager.RegisterFrame(rootFrame, "appframe"); 
                if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                {
                }

                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
```

**EDIT:**
The problem was that I needed to add a basic page in my blank template. This auto generates some classes needed to do basic functionality. Below is a screenshot of the minimum items that the common folder needs to contain. 
[image: Common Folder Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the Common folder present in your project? This folder is usually included in the Visual Studio 2012 App project templates (except the Blank App template) which contains a bunch of classes with boilerplate code for layout, styles and other functionality.

If you created your project with a Blank App template, you may not have this. To get it included, create a new Basic Page (Right-click on your Project > Add > New Item > (Visual C#)* > Basic Page), and Visual Studio will ask if you would like to create these files.

*I'm not sure what this is for VB .NET or WinJS, but I assume it would be the same structure.

Comment: I am doing C# and I believe I have this folder. I made a blank app and I believe I added that page but I will double check and get back to you. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: This was it exactly. I had the common folder it just didn't contain all the necessary classes. I have updated my original question of what the common folder needs in order to run. Thanks so much.